# ggplot2 defined Y-axis and boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the PCR values of 6 genes into multiple bar plots using ggplot2/facet_wrap. (1) The y-axis of the plot is showing specific values and it looks awkward with longer decimal places.
(2) The box plots are not visible, when i use facet_wrap.

CODE:

```
PCR <- read_excel("2019-09 qPCR.xlsx", 1)
PCRvar <- melt(data = PCR, id.vars = 1)   #listed the variables 
ggplot(data = PCRvar, mapping = aes(x = Group, y = value, fill = Group)) + 
facet_wrap(~variable) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

FILES: Excel, Plots 
http://ge.tt/5yTvCtx2

Question:

(1) I want to show only specific values. Can we define the y-axis range and intervals (Example Range: -5 to +5, interval=0.5) ?

(2) Box plots are not visible? Can anyone provide a solution.

[image: Boxplot_ggplot2/Facet_multiple Plots]

Comment: Looks like your y-axis values are of type factor, not numeric. Note that there are values that contain characters - these will be read as factors by default. This explains the axis label appearance and the boxplot issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the y-axis range, see `?ylim` or `?scale_y_continuous`.

Your next problem is that `reshape2::melt()` was used incorrectly, so you have values with characters in the `value` column:

```
reshape2::melt(PCR, id.vars = 1) %>% str()

'data.frame':   42 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Group   : chr  "Basal" "Basal" "Basal" "TGFb" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 7 levels "Treatment","P14",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ value   : chr  "Basal_1" "Basal_2" "Basal_3" "TGFb_1" ...
```

I would suggest `tidyr::gather()` instead.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

PCR %>% gather(Var, Val, -Group, -Treatment) %>% str()

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   36 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Group    : chr  "Basal" "Basal" "Basal" "TGFb" ...
 $ Treatment: chr  "Basal_1" "Basal_2" "Basal_3" "TGFb_1" ...
 $ Var      : chr  "P14" "P14" "P14" "P14" ...
 $ Val      : num  0 0 0 3.02 2.87 ...
```

Boxplot should now give the expected result:

```
PCR %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -Group, -Treatment) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Group, y = Val, fill = Group)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Var) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

**However:** given the small number of values and the fact that many of the controls = 0, I would suggest showing the individual observations rather than using a boxplot:

```
PCR %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -Group, -Treatment) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Group, y = Val, color = Group)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Var) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer  #neilfws. I am a biologist. Was learning R and was struggling to solve it in weekend. Love and many thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I was also a biologist learning R, a long time ago :) Stick with it, it is worth the effort.

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Comment: Another question is, after I added more conditions to the table to plot a single boxplot, the x-axis is not the same order as in the dataframe.
CODE: PCR <- read_excel("2019-09 qPCRm.xlsx", 1) PCR %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Group, y = P14, fill = Group)) + geom_boxplot().

Comment: I tried different solutions from stackoverflow older posts, like aes(x=reorder(Group, P14), y=P14, fill=Group)) or  aes(fct_infreq(factor(Group)), y=P14, fill=Group)), but they sorted the x-axis in Alphabetical order. 
Could you please suggest to get the expected order as in excel: Basal, ATII-100, ATII-200, TGFb, TNFa.

Comment: Please post new questions as new questions. Not as comments or answers to this one.

Comment: Apologies neil,  I didnt know that. I have made a new post of my second question.